# React: How to modify a state variable by matching against the value of another state variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, state

I am building a front end for a facial recognition app, and it is my first time using react. I am having a hard time working out how to match the value of one of my state variables to another as a way of identifying what object to modify the state of. Let me lay out the scenario.

I have state variables defined that look like this:

`this.state = {current_name: '', correct: 0,
    people: [
    {name: 'Alice', here: "Not Here"},
    {name: 'Bob', here: "Not Here"}]}`

The string "current_name" gets updated every half second by making a request to an external endpoint to stream who is in frame. I also have a handler for updating state that looks like this:

```
  CorrectHandler(){
this.setState(prevState =>({
  correct: prevState.correct + 1
}));}
```

which I am triggering with an "onclick" event in my app.

What I would like to be able to do is include in my handler a function to identify a person by the value of their name i.e. "Bob", and change the state of "here" atribute to to a new string.

It seems like there is probably a very simple solution to this but I'm too new to react and javascript to see it. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the best way to do this is using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to change your `people` array into one with new values, like this:

```
function updateSpecificPerson(person) {
    if ( person.name === "Bob" ) {
        //it's Bob! Make a shallow copy of him with his new "here" value
        return Object.assign({}, person, { here: "somewhere" });
    }
    // it's not Bob - leave the object alone
    return person;
}

this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
       //copy over all the people, except Bob, who gets modified during copy
       people: prevState.people.map(updateSpecificPerson)
    };
});
```

Should be straightforward to change `Bob` and `somewhere` to variables you control.

Comment: Hi Duncan, I appreciate your answer and I have a couple quick questions if you have the time for me!

-What do you mean by "change to variables you control"? do I need to be handling them differently than I am now?

- wouldn't this mean if I have to handle 50 different names I would need 50 different if else checks? I would think there would be some way of using the value as a key instead, but I don't know what that would look like.

Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Never mind, got it working! just had to pass "this" as a second argument in "map", and do "person.name === this.state.current_name". Thank you!